# Ruby on Rails: two references with different name to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, reference

My app has a model called `User` (it includes the email adress, username..)
I want to create a model `Message` it should have two fields `sender` and `recipient`. Both are references to the `User` model. I tried this:

```
rails generate model Message sender:references recipient:references
```

Rails generated this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender
  belongs_to :recipient
end
```

But I don't want two different models. Both fields should reference to `User`. I'm running Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.2. Any help is highly appreciated. Please ask me if you need more information about my problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify the class name of the association, [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to)

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Comment: This makes sense but I want to understand exactly what to put in the rails generate command.  Do you use: rails generate model Message user:references

Comment: You can instead of putting references in the generator, place `sender_id` and `recipient_id` as integers, and let Rails do the wiring.