# Ruby on Rails 6 ActiveRecord associations, one model with multiple references to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I am building a Ruby on Rails 6 application where I have a model `Archive`, and a another model `ArchiveAgencies`. In the `Archive` model I must have a sender agency and a receiver agency, which should represent `ArchiveAgencies`.

After going through the Rails docs, and some StackOverflow QA:

- [How do I add migration with multiple references to the same model in one table? Ruby/Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867981/how-do-i-add-migration-with-multiple-references-to-the-same-model-in-one-table)
- [Defining two references to the same column in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131916/defining-two-references-to-the-same-column-in-another-table)
- [Ruby on Rails: two references with different name to the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908930/ruby-on-rails-two-references-with-different-name-to-the-same-model)

I came up with this approach:

### Models

```
class Archive < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender_agency, class_name: ArchiveAgencies, foreign_key: "sender_agency_id"
  belongs_to :receiver_agency, class_name: ArchiveAgencies, foreign_key: "receiver_agency_id"
end
```

```
class ArchiveAgency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :archives, inverse_of: 'sender_agency'
  has_many :archives, inverse_of: 'receiver_agency'
end
```

### Migration

```
class CreateArchiveAgencies < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :archives do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateArchives < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :archives do |t|
      t.references :sender_agency, foreign_key: { to_table: :archive_agencies }
      t.references :receiver_agency, foreign_key: { to_table: :archive_agencies }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Is this the best approach for this case?
Would, having two `inverse_of` statements in the model `ArchiveAgency` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare multiple associations with the same name the last one will overwrite the others.

Instead you need to use unique names for each association and configure them properly:

```
class ArchiveAgency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :archives_as_sender, 
     inverse_of: :sender_agency,
     foreign_key: :sender_agency_id,
     class_name: 'Archive'

  has_many :archives_as_receiver, 
     inverse_of: :receiver_agency,
     foreign_key: :receiver_agency_id,
     class_name: 'Archive'
end

class Archive < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender_agency, # foreign_key can be derived from the name
     class_name: 'ArchiveAgency', # needs to be a string - not the class itself
     inverse_of: :archives_as_sender 
  belongs_to :receiver_agency, 
     class_name: 'ArchiveAgency'
     inverse_of: :archives_as_receiver
end
```